# trying to run sqlcmd fails, unable to establish connection?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

When I try to run sqlcmd (from the cmd prompt) I get the following error:

> HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in
>   stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
>   . Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
>   f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
>    SQL Server Books Online..
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Not sure why this happens? I can connect to the sql server from within my asp.net website (which runs locally, like the database) but sqlcmd can't connect.

Comment: Have you provided your credentials?

Comment: Can you show us the parameters for SQLCMD that you're using??

Comment: Can you show us the parameters for SQLCMD that you're using??

Comment: All I'm doing is typing in sqlcmd from cmd.exe..

Comment: SQLCMD.exe -S SERVER -d DATABASE -U USER -P PASSWORD

Comment: If you can connect from within your ASP.NET application, what connection string are you using? This may help give us clues to what you need to pass through to sqlcmd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `sqlcmd -S <InstanceName>`

- Your command will work only if you have installed the server as default instance.
- Run sp_helpserver to know the instance name.

Answer (score 14):

If you are not using the default instance, the try then following command:

```
sqlcmd -S MACHINENAME\INSTANCE_NAME
```

Notice the capital S. Also notice that I did not give it a user of password, given that default sqlcmd authentication is the windows auth, so I can log in as the current user.
 For more information from Microsoft check this out > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx

Comment: thank you for pointing out the case-sensitivity of the argument flag

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone, but I tried the machine name and it did not work for me - I had to use "localhost".  I have TCP/IP enabled (for local development), and had to use "localhost" instead of the actual name (seems that the TCP/IP listener was listening only on some IPv6 addresses [which my machine name resolves to], and the loopback address [127.0.0.1] as well, which was the only thing that worked [IPv6 bug?]).