# Unable to login to SQL Server 2008 through command line utility

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio and am able to login to the database through this. I have also installed the SQL command utility. But, am unable to login through the command utility. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd
HResult 0x274D, Level 16, State 1
TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively re
fused it.
```

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A
>   network-related or in stance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server . Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i f SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see  SQL
>   Server Books Online.. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

I tried giving the server name, username and password explicitly using:

```
sqlcmd -S <hostname\database instance> -U <user> -P <pwd>
```

this too doesn't help.

I need this command utility for my automation stuff. Please help me!

Comment: are you able to connect through ssms

Comment: possible duplicate of [trying to run sqlcmd fails, unable to establish connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012526/trying-to-run-sqlcmd-fails-unable-to-establish-connection)

Comment: It would help if you included more precise details: is the instance default or named, are you connecting to a local or remote server, what network protocols are enabled etc. However this question really belongs on the DBA site.

Answer (score 2):

At first blush, it sounds to me like your SQL Server Management Studio is connecting via a different network library, such as Named Pipes, while the sqlcmd client is attempting to connect via TCP, and the server isn't listening there (or perhaps on a non-standard port). That's why you're getting the TCP error in the latter instance.

Comment: I am using the default instance. An instance <hostname>\OVOPS is created when I installed the HP Operations Management server. I am trying to connect to this default instance and it is successful from the studio. I have disabled named pipes through SQL Server Configuration Manager. Only TCP/IP and Shared Memory are in enabled state. I have also added an inbound rule to listen on 1433 port for TCP protocol. But this doesn't help. And I am connecting to a local server.

Comment: Thanks guys! It worked now. I am not sure what exactly has solved the problem. After doing the changes, I mentioned above - disabled named pipes through SQL Server Configuration Manager, added an inbound rule to listen on 1433 port for TCP protocol and restarted the SQL Server Services, I haven't restarted my system. I restarted my system and tried connecting using the string:

sqlcmd -S ,hostname>\OVOPS
and it worked!