# Execute sql script using sqlcmd.exe

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S(local) -U(sa) -P(password) -i F:\sql.sql
```

> HResult 0x3, Level 16, State 1 Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server [3]. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in stance-specific error has
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server . Server is not
>   found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i f SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
>   see  SQL Server Books Online.. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

```
How I resolve this problem
```

Comment: Can you connect via SSMS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11472346/62576, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12326724/62576

Comment: have you tried using this command from sql command tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this query on this folder window->system32, because every sql command executes in this folder..

```
C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -S(local) -U(sa) -P(password) -i F:\sql.sql
```